# Change Lights Brightness

Tags: animation

i have downloaded a police car model with its lights. I've noticed that their brightness is too high, and they're already keyframed to display the light pattern.

Is there a way to change their own brightness collectively? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the lights, open the *Graph Editor*, select all the curves (make sure that you only select the curves relative to their *Power*) and move them down in order to decrease their power at once:

[image]